# x86 IMUL result is correct, why?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
    MOV EAX,0XB504F333
    MOV ECX,0XB504F333
    ;EAX = B504F333
    ;ECX = B504F333
    IMUL ECX ;RESULT=
------------------------------
    ;EDX = 15F61998 ;it is incorrect the correct value is 7FFFFFFF
    ;EAX = 9EA1DC29 ;it is correct 
    ;Carry flag = 1
    ;Overflow flag = 1
    ;Sign flag = 0
```

It's no way to overflow because:

```
7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = 9223372036854775807 => sqrt(9223372036854775807) = 3037000499 = 0xB504F333
0xB504F333 * 0xB504F333 < 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (EDX:EAX)
```

Why overflow?

Thanks the replies.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're doing and what you're asking. It's odd to me that the presented code is not the actual code (`IMUL CX RESUL` won't compile), that you list 32-bit values and registers (`EAX = B504F333` and `ECX = B504F333`) and at the same time 16-bit registers (`IMUL CX RESUL`, `DX = 15F61998`, `AX = 9EA1DC29`, `7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (DX:AX)`). What are you actually doing and actually having problems with???

Comment: sorry i corrected, RESUL => RESULT

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't make sense. If the actual instruction is `IMUL CX`, the result in DX:AX must be `00A3:DC29` and yet you're saying it's `1998:DC29`. Give us the actual code and data.

Comment: sorry i'm tired, everywhere i use 32 bit (ecx,ebx,edx,eax) registers.

Comment: Please do everyone and yourself a favor, don't distort or omit important information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MOV EAX,0xB504F333
MOV ECX,0xB504F333
IMUL ECX
```

Must indeed produce `0x15F61998` in `EDX` and `0x9EA1DC29` in `EAX`. That's because `IMUL` treats its operands as signed.

In other words, since `0xB504F333` represents a negative value in 2's complement code (because its most significant bit is set), the instruction actually multiplies `0xB504F333-0x100000000=-1257966797` instead of `0xB504F333=3037000499` by itself.

And so the correct result is `0x15F619989EA1DC29=1582480462354439209` instead of `0x7FFFFFFF9EA1DC29=9223372030926249001`.

Since the 64-bit signed product in `EDX:EAX` is not the sign extended value of `EAX`, which means that the signed product doesn't fit into 32 bits, `IMUL` sets the carry and overflow flags to 1. This all is explained in the Intel and AMD CPU manuals.

If you use `MUL ECX` instead of `IMUL ECX`, you will get `0x7FFFFFFF9EA1DC29=9223372030926249001` in `EDX:EAX` and the overflow and carry flags will be set again because the now unsigned product still doesn't fit into 32 bits.

Comment: i just use 1 operand version IMUL ECX.

Comment: thank you, all is clear, sorry for the incorrect informations